# How is the space $C^\infty(\partial\Omega)$ defined?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n, n\in\mathbb{N}$ be open and bounded with $C^\infty$-boundary. What is the space $C^\infty(\partial\Omega)$? I found that expression in "Interpolation Theory Function Spaces Differential Operators" from Triebel on page 320 equation (1).

Is this the space of functions on $\partial\Omega$ that have an extension to $C^\infty(\overline{\Omega})$?

Comment: I've never read this book, but I think it may refer to the space of smooth functions in $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: @leo, the question is, what exactly is a smooth function on that set?

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you have a closed set $K$, or any set for that matter, then $C^\infty(K)$ is the set of functions $f:K\to\mathbb{R}^n$ that can be extended to functions in $C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: And smooth boundary would mean there are some (smooth) charts $\phi_i: U_i \to \partial \Omega$ such that a function $f : \partial \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is the restriction of some $F \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ iff $f \circ \phi_i$ is smooth for each $i$.

Comment: I am  not sure about the iff. Definitely if $f\in C^\infty (\partial\Omega)$ and $F$ is an extension, then $F\circ\phi_i$ would be smooth for ever chart. In the other direction, maybe playing with the implicit function theorem and partitions of unity....

Comment: I meant $U_i$ open $ \subset \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ and $\phi_i$ is a smooth homomorphism, so we see $C^\infty(\partial \Omega)$ as $C^\infty(M)$ for some $n-1$ dimensional manifold $M$. To show the iff, I would take $B$ an open ball containing $\Omega$, use that $C^\infty_c(\overline{B})$ as well as $C^\infty(M)$ are complete for the smooth topology, and say that $\{ F|_{\partial \Omega}, F \in C^\infty_c(B)\}$ is dense in $C^\infty(M)$.